# Сравнить 2 даты в 2 методах

Tags: java

Написала вот такой код:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class DepositAccount extends BankAccount
{
    @Override
    public void put(double amountToPut) {
        LocalDate lastIncome = LocalDate.now();
        if (amountToPut >= 0) {
            balance = amountToPut + balance;
            System.out.println(balance);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Введённая сумма меньше нуля");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void take(double amountToTake) {
        if (amountToTake <= balance) {
            balance = balance - amountToTake;
            System.out.println(balance);
        }
        else if (amountToTake < 0) {
            System.out.println("Введённая сумма меньше нуля");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("На счету недостаточно денег");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class BankAccount {

    double balance = 0;

    public double getAmount() {
        return balance;
    }
    public void put(double amountToPut) {
        if (amountToPut >= 0) {
            balance = amountToPut + balance;
            System.out.println(balance);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Введённая сумма меньше нуля");
        }
    }

    public void take(double amountToTake) {
        if (amountToTake <= balance) {
            balance = balance - amountToTake;
            System.out.println("Ваш баланс: " + balance);
        }
        else if (amountToTake < 0) {
            System.out.println("Введённая сумма меньше нуля");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("На счету недостаточно денег");
        }
    }
```

В классе DepositAccount нужно сверить дату снятия денег с датой lastIncome. Если с даты lastIncome прошёл 1 месяц, то деньги снять можно. Если нет, то должна быть ошибка. Не понимаю, как можно это сделать. Можете помочь и подсказать, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам стоит хранить переменную с датой последнего пополнения и обновлять её при каждой операции пополнения. Проверять что между датами прошло достаточно времени можно так:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MM yyyy");
        LocalDate lastIncome = LocalDate.parse("10 10 2020", formatter);
        if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.now(), lastIncome) > 30) {
            System.out.println("Можно снять деньги");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ещё не прошло 30 дней");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, если `amountToTake` меньше, чем `balance`, то она может быть и меньше, чем 0, т.е. поменять местами блоки сравнения в `take()`.

Теперь по вопросу. Думаю, следовало бы сохранить дату в общую для всего класса переменную.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class DepositAccount extends BankAccount {

    LocalDate lastIncome = null;

    @Override
    public void put(double amountToPut) {
        if (amountToPut >= 0) {
            lastIncome = LocalDate.now();
            balance += amountToPut;
            System.out.println(balance);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Введённая сумма меньше нуля");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void take(double amountToTake) {
        if (amountToTake < 0) {
            System.out.println("Введённая сумма меньше нуля");
        } else if (amountToTake <= balance) {
            if (lastIncome == null) {
                System.out.println("Не было пополнений");
            } else if (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(lastIncome, LocalDate.now()) >= 30) {
                balance -= amountToTake;
                System.out.println(balance);
            } else {
                System.out.println("С последнего пополнения прошло менее 30 дней");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("На счету недостаточно денег");
        }
    }
}
```